# How to alternate my sounds on my java program?

Tags: java

This goes along with my last question - I got the rooster sound to repeat every five seconds, but now I had to add a cow sound and a black background. Every five seconds, the rooster sound and the white background should alternate with the cow sound and black background. However, while my program is compiling, it just plays the rooster sound, then the cow sound, and doesn't change the background color. Help!

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Morning extends JFrame
     implements ActionListener
{
  private EasySound rooster;
  private EasySound cow;
  private int time;

  public Morning()
  {
    super("Morning");
    rooster = new EasySound("roost.wav");
    rooster.play();

    cow = new EasySound("cow2.wav");
    cow.play();

    time = 0;
    Timer clock = new Timer(5000, this);
    clock.start();

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Morning morning = new Morning();
    morning.setSize(300, 150);
    morning.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    morning.setVisible(true);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    Container c = getContentPane();
    if (time == 5000)
      {
        rooster.play();
        c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        time = 0;
      }
    if (time == 0)
      {
       cow.play();
       c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
       time++;
      }
  }
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Thank you to whoever helps!
Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the second `if` with an `else`.
Since you also used `if` for the second condition, as soon as you reset the `time` to `0`, then the background is set to white again; giving the impression that it's not changed.

**UPDATED**:

I think you would want to change it to black first, since initially the background is already white.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (time == 0) {
        rooster.play();
        c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        time += 5000;
    }
    else /*if (time == 5000)*/ {
        cow.play();
        c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        time = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did what you said, but the program is still playing the rooster sound immediately followed by the cow sound and the background stays white. Any suggestions?